# Scanning the universe - edit: expanding or shrinking

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background

I know that this may sound as a very basic question, but how come that we can
detect CMB radiation, light or gravitational waves from the big-bang era? 
Shouldn't this radiation has overtaken us a long time ago?

**EDIT**: if i got it right , the answer to my question has to do with  space-expansion , but to be honest i can't understand why.

**In an hypothetical situation that universe stops expanding and starts shrinking, we won't be able to  detect such radiations anymore?**

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The radiation that is hitting us now *originated* from $\frac {300,000 km} z$ =~ $\frac {300,000}{1100}$ =~ $270 km$ further away than the radiation that was hitting us a second ago

Comment: @igael: Hah! You are correct... I totally forgot about the correction for the expansion. You should write that as an answer. You'll get my upvote. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: if i got it right , the answer to my question has to do with space-expansion , but to be honest i can't understand why.
>
> In an hypothetical situation that universe stops expanding and starts shrinking, we won't be able to detect such radiations anymore?

One has to think of our  three dimensions we live in and the effect of expansion or shrinking, in a novel way. Intuition comes with the model of the surface of a balloon and the [raisin bread](http://cmb.physics.wisc.edu/pub/tutorial/hubble.html) analogies.

Let us take the surface of a balloon, and imagine that before we blow it out it was very small ( the beginning of the expansion) . As we blow it out the surface expands. In the two dimensional world of the surface of the balloon, an ant, for example will see all points on a ( for the ant hypothetical/mathematical) sphere surface receding from each other. In the ants world at the beginning of time all surface points were one and the same point.

The raisin bread analogy is a three dimensional analogue how space defined by the dough expands, and all points move away from each other.

In the current model of the universe, each of us are at the center of the original expansion, and the light that decoupled at [380.000 years after the big bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:History_of_the_Universe.svg) is coming at us from all other points in the universe, and the light from our point streams out to the rest of the universe. The [red shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) of the spectra of known atoms allows us to measure the expansion of galaxies from each other. The CMB keeps on coming because time keeps on counting the beginning of the universe in the four dimensional space. It is not a "wave front" that can pass , because it is everywhere due to the four dimensional space.

If there were shrinking, i.e. galaxies would be nearing each other and us, there would be a  universal blue shift and we would be measuring shrinking and not expansion. We would still be detecting the radiation, and it would tell us of the shrinking of the universe instead of the expansion it is telling us now.

Comment: @ anna v : Thank you for your answer! I am aware of the analogy
of the expanding surface of a ballon but i think the key-point phrase in your answer that makes things more clear is this: 'The CMB keeps on coming because time keeps on counting the beginning of the universe in the four dimensional space. It is not a "wave front" that can pass , because it is everywhere due to the fourdimensional space.'

Comment: @ anna v: Of course the analogy of the 2D surface of a balloon is the best way of visualizing the situation. But this analogy arises another problems
because humans senses can perceive a 4D universe and implies that it's a closed-finite area.So the expansion of space has to do only with the red shift of the CMB radiation? How much can an EM wave be 'streched' or red shifted?

Comment: going to the limit of wavelength approaching infinity. Then one gets into  questions unresolved as yet quantum gravity , whether a photon can have a wavelength/frequency larger than the observable universe for example. The expansion is measured from atomic radiation from galaxies showing redshift. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble's_law

Answer (score 1):

The universe is expanding - and it is expanding, as far as we can tell, in all directions, at the same rate, everywhere all at once. So over a given period of time, a distance of 1000 units will become 1100 units, and in another passing of the same time, that distance will become 1210 units long, then 1321 units, and so on. Any radiation emitted beyond a certain distance will find it difficult to catch up, given that it must travel at a fixed speed.

As a result, and due to a point in time at the beginning of the Big Bang where everything was intensely small, hot and energetic, we're unable to see beyond a particular point in time. It's this hot and energetic state we see evidence of in the background radiation. It's both the edge, and the beginning of our universe.